# Tween rotation in Easeljs: Control direction of rotation

Tags: rotation, easeljs, tween

I have some shapes on the stage. Some of them I want to tween rotate clockwise, some counterclockwise.

The rotation property for objects in Easel.js runs from 0 to 360 (I think). So...if I want to tween the rotation of an object counterclockwise from 45 degrees to -45 degrees...a change of 90 degrees...how do I do that?

Thanks in advance. Roger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, TweenJS tweens rotation the same as any other number:
* If you go from 45 to -45, it will rotate counter-clockwise
* If you go from 45 to 300, it will rotate clockwise

You can use the SmartRotation plugin with the latest tagged version of TweenJS in the CDN (0.6.2) to ensure it rotates the "shortest" distance, so in the second example above, it will rotate counter-clockwise instead. You can find it in the "plugins" directory.

However, a better option is to use the latest TweenJS NEXT version (yet to be released on the CDN), where you can use the RotationPlugin (in src/tweenjs/plugins), which has the same "shortest distance" behaviour as the old SmartRotation plugin, but also the ability to set the rotation direction per `to()` call:

```
myTween.get(foo)
    .to({rotation:30, rotationDir:-1})
    .to({rotation:60})
    .to({rotation:10, rotationDir:1});
```

The RotationPlugin automatically handles `rotation`, as well as `rotationX`, `rotationY`, and `rotationZ` properties.